# How to Apply --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure for Multiple Hosts in Playwright

Tags: javascript, http, web-scraping, firefox, playwright

I'm currently developing a web scraping application using Playwright with Firefox, where I need to interact with multiple insecure .onion origins (served over HTTP) as if they were secure. My goal is to avoid launching a new browser instance for each origin to save resources. Instead, I wish to launch a single browser instance and create multiple contexts or pages within it, treating each insecure origin as secure. Here's the snippet of my current approach:

```js
await firefox.launch({
    proxy: { server: 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050' },
    args: [`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=${host.slug}`],
    headless: true,
});
```

The **`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`** argument works fine for a single origin (**`host.slug`**), but I have a database of URLs that I need to treat as secure, and I'm looking for a way to apply this setting to multiple origins within a single browser instance.

1. I considered launching a browser instance for each URL with the **`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`** flag tailored to each URL. However, this approach is not resource-efficient (current implementation).
2. I looked into creating a new context for each URL, but I couldn't find a way to apply the **`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`** setting at the context level rather than at the browser launch level.

Is there a way in Playwright to launch a single browser instance and configure it to treat multiple specific insecure origins as secure, without launching a new browser for each origin? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to specify a list of origins to be treated as secure within a single browser instance or to dynamically add origins to this list as I process them.

Any guidance, workaround, or insight into how to achieve this with Playwright would be greatly appreciated.